# Organizing dependency on a recursive Makefile

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I have two Makefiles, one is for my app, and another one is for its dependent library. The library is linked together with the app. The library's Makefile is written using some third-party inclusions and therefore cannot be changed much (in particular, I cannot get rid of *recursive make* usage).

What I'm trying to achieve is automatic library (re)building as a prerequisite for the app linking rule.

I tried to do this using a special *stamp* file: roughly speaking, the library Makefile updates the *stamp* file whenever its rebuilding happens, and the app Makefile uses the *stamp* file as a prerequisite.

So my **app Makefile** looks like:

```
.PHONY: rebuild_libfoo
rebuild_libfoo:
    +make -C path/to/libfoo STAMPDIR=out out/libfoo.stamp
all: rebuild_libfoo
out/libfoo.stamp: rebuild_libfoo
app: out/libfoo.stamp <... additional prerequisites ...>
    <... recipe with linker execution ...>
all: app
```

and the **libfoo Makefile** looks like:

```
$(STAMPDIR)/libfoo.stamp: installation/libs/path/libfoo.a
    touch $(STAMPDIR)/libfoo.stamp
installation/libs/path/libfoo.a: <... additional prerequisites ...>
    <... recipe with ar execution ...>
all: installation/libs/path/libfoo.a
```

So what's good about this solution is that whenever I do "make all" in the app directory, the library is rebuilt whenever changes in it occur.

But there is a big problem also: the app linking rule is not being executed *automatically*. So, even if the library rebuild happened, the app is kept linked with the old library version. But, if I run "make all" in the app directory for the second time, then the app becomes linked with the new version - which is obviously a very error-prone behavior.

As far as I understand, that's because make reads all the timestamps *before* executing any recipes, so the "rebuild_libfoo" rule, despite touching the stamp file, has no immediate influence on the app linking rule.

Is there any workaround for this? Maybe, any way to force make re-reading file timestamps?

Comment: I think there is a solution, but could you explain how linking with the new version of the library is error-prone behavior? I don't quite see it.

Comment: Sorry, that was a bad wording. By "error-prone behavior" I meant linking with the **old** version of library during the first *make* execution. Moreover, this behavior is very misleading as it is displayed by *make* that the library itself **is** recompiled.

Answer (score 1):

The library needs to be a prerequisite for the target.  In the simplest form

```
app: out/libfoo.stamp <... additional prerequisites ...> path/to/libfoo/libfoo.a
        <... recipe with linker execution ...>
```

I am using GNU Make 3.81.  I have reduced the sample to the following files:

```
app.c
Makefile
path/to/libfoo/Makefile
path/to/libfoo/libsrc.c
```

Library Makefile:

```
CC = gcc
all: libfoo.a
libfoo.a:   libsrc.o
    $(AR) -r $@ $?

.PHONY: clean
clean:
    rm -f libsrc.o libfoo.a
```

The application Makefile

```
.DEFAULT_GOAL = all
LD = gcc

.PHONY: rebuild_libfoo
rebuild_libfoo:
    +make -C path/to/libfoo $(MAKECMDGOALS)

all: rebuild_libfoo app

app: app.o path/to/libfoo/libfoo.a

.PHONY: clean
clean:
    +make -C path/to/libfoo $(MAKECMDGOALS)
    rm -f app app.o
```

Issuing `make` in the application directory, I have

```
make -C path/to/libfoo 
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/digitemp/make/path/to/libfoo'
gcc    -c -o libsrc.o libsrc.c
ar -r libfoo.a libsrc.o
ar: creating libfoo.a
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/digitemp/make/path/to/libfoo'
cc    -c -o app.o app.c
cc   app.o path/to/libfoo/libfoo.a   -o app
```

Issuing the `make` command a second time, results in no compiles, etc. (as expected).  Then entering the command `touch path/to/libfoo/libsrc.c` followed by `make` results in the following:

```
make -C path/to/libfoo 
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/digitemp/make/path/to/libfoo'
gcc    -c -o libsrc.o libsrc.c
ar -r libfoo.a libsrc.o
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/digitemp/make/path/to/libfoo'
cc   app.o path/to/libfoo/libfoo.a   -o app
```

As expected, the library object file is compiled and the application linked.

Comment: This doesn't help, the app rule is not triggered when libfoo is changed.
Because the prerequisite "path/to/libfoo/libfoo.a" is checked by _make_ before the rule rebuild_libfoo works.